# Add new Datasource (mysql) wildfly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, wildfly

I'm trying to add new datasource mysql jdbc driver to my wildfly server

I created folder  wildfly.x.x.x/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main
I've got here jdbc jar file and module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.mysql">
        <resources>
         <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar"/>
     </resources>
     <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.api"/>
     </dependencies>
    </module>
```

then added dataresource code into standalone-full.xml (under datareources tag)

```
 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS" pool-name="MySQLDS"     enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
 <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</connection-url>
 <driver>MySQLDriver</driver>
<security>
 <user-name>root</user-name>
 <password></password>
</security>
</datasource>
```

but when i go to wildfly control panel `http://localhost:9990/console/`
dataresource doesnt appear , what did i missed?

also i'm trying to add it manually from interface i'v got this error

```
Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "mysql")
    ],
    "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010447: Connection is not valid",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you add a driver definition? Your `datasources` subsystem should look something like this:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/myds" pool-name="myds" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>foo</user-name>
                    <password>bar</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

The `driver` element in the data source definition must reference a `driver` element by name. The `module` attribute must match the name of your MySQL driver module.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I meet the same problem (I could add the datasources and test connection successfully before) So I'm just confused and I find a way works for me:)

See my services and I find it stopped,and I started it then tried again,It works well again! Even though your service does not stop, maybe just restart it.
I have to say it may not work for you if you never success to connect before,good luck~

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are [three ways](http://pvrworld-wildfly.blogspot.in/2016/11/getting-started-guide-wildfly.html) using which you can simply create datasource into wildfly

1. Using admin console
2. Manually adding into standalone.xml
3. Creating datasource file that is xml file.

Go to **WildFly directory/standalone/deployments**
Simplest way to create datasource xml with following content

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
      <datasource jndi-name="APP_DS" pool-name="APP_DS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME</connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        <driver>mysql</driver>

        <!-- sql to call when connection is created -->
        <new-connection-sql>SELECT 1</new-connection-sql>

        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
        </pool>

        <security>
          <user-name>username</user-name>
          <password>password</password>
        </security>

        <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool -->
        <validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        </validation>

        <timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>300000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
        </timeout>
        <statement>
        <track-statements>true</track-statements>
        </statement>      
      </datasource>
    </datasources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also create the database that you will use. Sometimes the reason for this error is that the database is missing.